# Need a method to filter data for records having more than one record for an id in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, group-by, hive, where-clause, bigdata

Consider the table below in HIVE:

[image]

Here i need to find out the unique combination of household,vehicle and customer.
But the condition is this.If for the same household and vehicle there are two different customers with role DRIVER and OWNER, i have to consider OWNER.
But if for a single household and vehicle there is only a single customer and if that customer is DRIVER or OWNER, i have to consider that record too.
I need HIVE query for this.

The result should be like below table:

[image]

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be useful, try this:-

```
select Household,Vehicle,Customer,Cust_role from (select *,row_number() 
over (partition by Household,Vehicle order by Cust_role desc) rn from test_table) tableouter where rn=1;
```

output:-

```
I       1       A       OWNER
II      2       C       DRIVER
III     3       D       OWNER
IV      4       E       OWNER
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friend!!

Comment: If you think this answer has solved or answered your question properly. Please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? for more information

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are looking for is a Top-N windowing function query, with N being 1 in your case. You can write a Hive query with RANK function with an additional "LIMIT 1" clause to achieve what you want. Refer [Rank function in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) to get started.

You can find a simple example here - [Hive - top n records within a group](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/24667/hive-top-n-records-within-a-group.html)